# How to improve speed of component creation in runtime

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I have a form where the user can create new tabs on a TPageControl. There is a 'master' tab and then when the user clicks to add tab, a new TTabSheet is created, replicating all the components inside the master tab : edits, checkboxes, comboxes etc.

When the user clicks to close the form, i then save the contents of the form the user created in a text file, so when the user open the form again, all the tabs he created are automatically show.

It's working fine, but the problem is , there is some cases where the user creates hundreds of tabs, let's say 200 or 300.

In this cases, my app is taking a long time to create the tabs in runtime. For instance, for 300 tabs, it's taking more than 1 minute in a i9 machine.

Is there something i could do to improve the speed of component creation ?

My code just read the textfile and loops whithin it to create each tab and each tab's inner components in runtime ; here is a snippet from it :

```
for i := pgtabsx.PageCount to tabcontx.Value do
        begin
          if i mod 10 = 0 then
            panelstatus.caption := 'Creating tabs (' + inttostr(i) + ' / ' + inttostr(tabcontx.Value) + ')...';
          if TTabSheet(FindComponent(tsx + inttostr(i))) = nil then
          begin
            newTab := TTabSheet.Create(self);
            newTab.Name :=  tsx + inttostr(i);
            {TTabSheet.Create(self).name := tsx + inttostr(i);
            newTab := TTabSheet(FindComponent(tsx + inttostr(i)));}
            with newTab do
            begin
              Caption := inttostr(i);
              pagecontrol := pgtabsx;
              Parent := pgtabsx;
              visible := true;
              pageindex := pgtabsx.PageCount - 1;
            end;
            pgtabsx.activepage := newTab;
            father := newTab;

            for j := 1 to length(tabcompsx) do
            begin
              o := tabcompsx[j];
              if o = nil then
                continue;
              oname := tabcompsx[j].name;

              if o is TPanel then
              begin
                n := df.noNumbers((o as TPanel).name) + inttostr(i);
                newPan := TPanel.Create(self);
                newPan.Name := n;
                {TPanel.Create(self).name := n;
                newPan := TPanel(FindComponent(n));
                with TPanel(FindComponent(n)) do}
                with newPan do
                begin
                  Parent := newTab;
                  height := (o as TPanel).height;
                  Width := (o as TPanel).Width;
                  Top := (o as TPanel).Top;
                  Left := (o as TPanel).Left;
                  align := (o as TPanel).align;
                  Caption := (o as TPanel).Caption;
                  ParentBackground := (o as TPanel).ParentBackground;
                  BevelInner := (o as TPanel).BevelInner;
                  bevelkind := (o as TPanel).bevelkind;
                  bevelouter := (o as TPanel).bevelouter;
                  BorderWidth := (o as TPanel).BorderWidth;
                  BorderStyle := (o as TPanel).BorderStyle;
                  visible := (o as TPanel).visible;
                end;
                father := newPan
              end
              else

                if o is tmemo then
                begin
                  n := df.noNumbers((o as tmemo).name) + inttostr(i);
                  {tmemo.Create(self).name := n;
                  with tmemo(FindComponent(n)) do}
                  with  tmemo.Create(self) do
                  begin
                    name := n;
                    Parent := father;
                    Top := (o as tmemo).Top;
                    Left := (o as tmemo).Left;
                    Width := (o as tmemo).Width;
                    height := (o as tmemo).height;
                    if (duplicaAba) and ((o as tmemo).Text <> '') then
                      Text := (o as tmemo).Text + ' ' + inttostr(i)
                    else
                      Text := '';
                    taborder := (o as tmemo).taborder;
                    charcase := (o as tmemo).charcase;
                    ScrollBars := (o as tmemo).ScrollBars;
                    BorderStyle := (o as tmemo).BorderStyle;
                    BevelInner := (o as tmemo).BevelInner;
                    bevelouter := (o as tmemo).bevelouter;
                    Tag := (o as tmemo).Tag;
                    align := (o as tmemo).align;
                    OnChange := (o as tmemo).OnChange;
                    visible := true;
                  end;
                end
                else
                  if o is tcombobox then
                  begin
                    n := df.noNumbers((o as tcombobox).name) + inttostr(i);
                    {tcombobox.Create(self).name := n;
                    with tcombobox(FindComponent(n)) do}
                    with tcombobox.Create(self) do
                    begin
                      name := n;
                      Parent := father;
                      Top := (o as tcombobox).Top;
                      Left := (o as tcombobox).Left;
                      Width := (o as tcombobox).Width;
                      items := (o as tcombobox).items;
                      taborder := (o as tcombobox).taborder;
                      charcase := (o as tcombobox).charcase;
                      Tag := (o as tcombobox).Tag;
                      style := (o as tcombobox).style;
                      itemindex := (o as tcombobox).itemindex;
                      visible := true;
                      style := (o as tcombobox).style;
                      OnDrawItem := (o as tcombobox).OnDrawItem;
                      OnChange := (o as tcombobox).OnChange;
                    end;
                  end
                  else
                    if o is TSpeedButton then
                    begin
                      n := df.noNumbers((o as TSpeedButton).name) + inttostr(i);
                      {TSpeedButton.Create(self).name := n;
                      with TSpeedButton(FindComponent(n)) do}
                      with TSpeedButton.Create(self) do
                      begin
                        name := n;
                        Parent := father;
                        Top := (o as TSpeedButton).Top;
                        Left := (o as TSpeedButton).Left;
                        height := (o as TSpeedButton).height;
                        Width := (o as TSpeedButton).Width;
                        Caption := (o as TSpeedButton).Caption;
                        Tag := (o as TSpeedButton).Tag;
                        font := (o as TSpeedButton).font;
                        visible := (o as TSpeedButton).visible;
                        OnClick := (o as TSpeedButton).OnClick;
                      end;
                    end
                    else
                      if o is TLabel then
                      begin
                        n := df.noNumbers((o as TLabel).name) + inttostr(i);
                        {TLabel.Create(self).name := n;
                        with TLabel(FindComponent(n)) do}
                        with TLabel.Create(self) do
                        begin
                          name := n;
                          Parent := father;
                          Top := (o as TLabel).Top;
                          Left := (o as TLabel).Left;
                          height := (o as TLabel).height;
                          Width := (o as TLabel).Width;
                          Caption := (o as TLabel).Caption;
                          Tag := (o as TLabel).Tag;
                          Alignment := (o as TLabel).Alignment;
                          align := (o as TLabel).align;
                          autosize := (o as TLabel).autosize;
                          cursor := (o as TLabel).cursor;
                          Width := (o as TLabel).Width;
                          WordWrap := (o as TLabel).WordWrap;
                          visible := (o as TLabel).visible;
                          OnClick := (o as TLabel).OnClick;
                        end;
                      end
                      else
                        if o is TEdit then
                        begin
                          if pos('_', (o as TEdit).name) > 0 then
                          begin
                            n := ansireplacestr(df.noNumbers((o as TEdit).name), '_', '');
                            n := n + inttostr(i);
                            aux := (o as TEdit).name;
                            Delete(aux, 1, pos('_', aux));
                            n := n + '_' + aux;
                          end
                          else
                            n := df.noNumbers((o as TEdit).name) + inttostr(i);
                          {TEdit.Create(self).name := n;
                          with TEdit(FindComponent(n)) do}
                          with TEdit.Create(self) do
                          begin
                            name := n;
                            Parent := father;
                            Top := (o as TEdit).Top;
                            Left := (o as TEdit).Left;
                            Width := (o as TEdit).Width;
                            if (duplicaAba) and ((o as TEdit).Text <> '') and (pos('c:\', (o as TEdit).Text) = 0) then
                              Text := (o as TEdit).Text + ' ' + inttostr(i)
                            else
                              Text := '';
                            taborder := (o as TEdit).taborder;
                            passwordchar := (o as TEdit).passwordchar;
                            charcase := (o as TEdit).charcase;
                            Tag := (o as TEdit).Tag;
                            onKeyPress := (o as TEdit).onKeyPress;
                            visible := (o as TEdit).visible;
                          end;
                        end
                        else
                          if o is tmaskedit then
                          begin
                            if pos('_', (o as tmaskedit).name) > 0 then
                            begin
                              n := ansireplacestr(df.noNumbers((o as tmaskedit).name), '_', '');
                              n := n + inttostr(i);
                              aux := (o as tmaskedit).name;
                              Delete(aux, 1, pos('_', aux));
                              n := n + '_' + aux;
                            end
                            else
                              n := df.noNumbers((o as tmaskedit).name) + inttostr(i);
                            {tmaskedit.Create(self).name := n;
                            with tmaskedit(FindComponent(n)) do}
                            with tmaskedit.Create(self) do
                            begin
                              name := n;
                              Parent := father;
                              Top := (o as tmaskedit).Top;
                              Left := (o as tmaskedit).Left;
                              Width := (o as tmaskedit).Width;
                              editmask := (o as tmaskedit).editmask;
                              if (duplicaAba) and ((o as tmaskedit).Text <> '') then
                                Text := (o as tmaskedit).Text + ' ' + inttostr(i)
                              else
                                Text := '';
                              taborder := (o as tmaskedit).taborder;
                              passwordchar := (o as tmaskedit).passwordchar;
                              charcase := (o as tmaskedit).charcase;
                              Tag := (o as tmaskedit).Tag;
                              onKeyPress := (o as tmaskedit).onKeyPress;
                              visible := (o as tmaskedit).visible;
                            end;
                          end
                          else
                            if o is TCheckBox then
                            begin
                              n := df.noNumbers((o as TCheckBox).name) + inttostr(i);
                              {TCheckBox.Create(self).name := n;
                              with TCheckBox(FindComponent(n)) do}
                              with TCheckbox.Create(self) do
                              begin
                                name := n;
                                Parent := father;
                                Top := (o as TCheckBox).Top;
                                Left := (o as TCheckBox).Left;
                                Caption := (o as TCheckBox).Caption;
                                Width := (o as TCheckBox).Width;
                                visible := (o as TCheckBox).visible;
                                taborder := (o as TCheckBox).taborder;
                                Tag := (o as TCheckBox).Tag;
                                align := (o as TCheckBox).align;
                                Alignment := (o as TCheckBox).Alignment;
                                if (duplicaAba) or (pos('tscb', n) > 0) then
                                  checked := (o as TCheckBox).checked;
                                OnClick := (o as TCheckBox).OnClick;
                              end;
                            end;
            end;
          end;
        end;
```

Comment: I haven't used Delphi in ages, so this may be outdated information, but back in the day container controls used to have a pair of BeginUpdate/EndUpdate methods that you could call before/after making wholesale changes like this, which would speed up the process a great deal.

Comment: Doing this `TTabSheet.Create(self).name  := tsx + inttostr(i)` only to call `FindComponent(tsx + inttostr(i))` on the next line isn't going to contribute to great performance.

Comment: @KenBourassa I replaced to "newTab := TTabSheet.Create(self);
            newTab.Name :=  tsx + inttostr(i);" but no improvement overall

Comment: @delphirules You _only_ replaced TTabsheet.create?  Replace them all! Also, using `father` instead of `self` as the owner of your created controls could potentially improve performance too.

Comment: @KenBourassa I replaced all and updated the code in question. Even so, i didnt see a significant improvement in speed , actually it became slower :-0

Comment: having dozens of `as` per object doesn't help either. `(o as tmemo)` isn't free. Use a proper variable. `if o is TMemo then vMemo := TMemo(o);` and then use vMemo. (same for all cases).  Maybe not super significant, but that will still improve efficiency.

Comment: I would try removing that line to see what happens. `pgtabsx.activepage := newTab;`.  But beyond that, I think that's all the inefficiency I can spot without profiling your code. My bet would be TComponent.Notification is one of the bottleneck. Anything with Align <> alNone would be expensive too. (You could call DisableAlign/EnableAlign for this one)

Comment: I had the same problem.  What I opted to do was set all .visible properties of all controls to false for tabs that aren't yet open.  Then in the PageControl.OnChange event, iterate all controls  for the new visible tab to true.  As a test, using your same code, set all controls .visible to false and report back the time.

Comment: One option would be to load/save data to one set of controls as a tab is navigated. Like what is done when using a database with data aware controls.

Comment: Don't use `FindComponent()` at all, that is going to search every control that is owned by the Form. Iterate though the `TPageControl.Pages[]` property instead. And you don't have to name each page, either. You can use the `TTabSheet.Tag` property to hold your index values, and then look for those values while iterating. Also, doing things like `(o as TPanel)` over and over the way you are is WAY overkill and will hamper performance since it is a dynamic lookup at runtime. You don't need `as` at all in this code, just use hard casts instead, eg: `height := TPanel(o).height;`

Comment: @JohnEasley for something like what you describe, I would probably opt to put the controls on a `TFrame` instead, where `TFrame` objects are created and destroyed as the user switches between tabs. That way, controls that are not visible are not kept in memory. You can use the `TTabSheet.OnShow` and `TTabSheet.OnHide` events to save and load each Frame's data as needed.

Comment: @JohnEasley Thank you for the hint ! Actually just by making the main Pagecontrol visible := false before tabs creation, improved the overall performance in about 50% !